# equal distributed percentage calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript, percentage

```
function percentify(num, param){
    for(var i=(param==true?0:1),array=[]; i<=num; i++)
        array.push( (param==true?i:1)*100/num )
    return array
}

console.log( percentify(7,true)[5] );
```

Comment: Could you add your expected and actual output, please?

Comment: what do you expect the output to be in your example

Comment: I assume you are talking about the number of decimal places displayed for the numbers? This is to do with inaccuracies in representing decimal values. Use toFixed if you want to display the numbers consistently.

Comment: I expected to have 7 splitted in 7 parts, each representing the amount of percentage on 100

Comment: can you give actual results rather than a vague description

Comment: are you expecting something like 14.28, 28.57, 42.86 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a guess at the solution .. interpreting "7 split into 7 parts each representing the amount of percentage on 100"

```
function eqPercentify(num){
    for(var i=1,result=[]; i<=num; i++){
        result.push(i * 100 / num);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log( eqPercentify(7) );
```

output

```
Array [ 14.285714285714286, 28.571428571428573, 42.857142857142854, 57.142857142857146, 71.42857142857143, 85.71428571428571, 100 ]
```